# VS2008 on Win 7 cannot write resources file. Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, png, gif, tiff

We load a C# project out of TFS, click on the solution and it builds fine on XP, but dies on Windows 7, with multiple

> Cannot write "C:...\projectName.resources." Parameter is not valid.

and one error that mentioned GDI+.  Web searches turn up hits about constructing GIF objects in a program, but little about this problem except suggestions to replace all images with PNG's, with some posts implicating alpha channel problems in the Bitmap class. I tried that approach for TIF's and it made the GDI error go away, but some of the images are animated GIF's that our users are trained on and we don't want to change those. Another suggestion was to replace the Bitmap class with a third party version, which seems kind of drastic and it is not free, so we didn't try it yet.

On 7 the build also fails from the command line, and it fails for GIF's from the XP project or ones new'ed on Win 7 from the designer now.

- Is it really the case the VisualStudio 2008 running on Win 7 only
  supports PNG's?
- But then why would designer let users add a GIF, and then give this error at build time?

The few posts I find are from 2011 and blame the Bitmap class. Looks like a single class could have been straightened out by now, if that is in fact the problem.

Comment: In case it helps anyone, we changed all the icons to TIFF and it was OK after that.